# Adjust spacing between text lines brightscript

Tags: fonts, roku, brightscript

Bellow is the code to show a string in Roku using **roImageCanvas**

```
 canvas = CreateObject("roImageCanvas")    
 port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
 canvas.SetMessagePort(port)
 items = []

 items.Push({
  Text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
  TextAttrs:{ font: "small", color: "#a0a0a0" ,Direction:"LeftToRight",HAlign:"Left",VAlign:"top"}
  TargetRect: {x: 550, y: 75, w: 300, h: 500}
 })

 canvas.SetLayer(0, { Color: "#ff000000", CompositionMode: "Source" })
 canvas.SetLayer(1, items)
 canvas.Show()
```

This will create an output like bellow
[image]

Is it possible to adjust the space between each line?

Note:I need to use **roImageCanvas**,because this page require some graphics with images

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to control spacing on the roImageCanvas is to break the text into separate strings with their own TargetRects.